# AC randomly shuts down after a few hours running

Tags: electrical, hvac

I have a window AC unit that shuts off after a few (4 or so) hours turned on.

By "shuts off" I mean all the mechanical components of the AC - fan and compressor - stop working. The AC is completely silent. However, the electronic components are still "turned on": if I press the "on/off" button on the remote, it *turns off*, not on. If I press it again, it turns on and runs for a few minutes before the same random shutdown happening.

This is a 10.2A, 890W inverter AC. My best guess right now is that there is that the outlet I'm plugging it into has inadequate wiring (which is surprising, 10.2A really isn't that much), the wires heat more than they should, and there must be some physical phenomena that lowers the input voltage enough that the AC shuts down.

I have tried 3 different ACs and I get the same result with all of them, so its not a product defect.

I have tried multiple outlets in different circuits. The circuit breaker does not trip, nor does the GHCI outlet trip (there's one in one of the circuits I tested).

1. Is there a name for what is happening? Between "annoying" and "it will eventually burn down your house", how dangerous is it?
2. What is my best bet at solving this? Should I just open a few different outlets until I find some with thicker-gauged wires? I thought about using the clothes drier outlet, but I just read they are 240V (regular outlets here are 120V).

If it matters at all, I'm in western Canada.

Comment: Doublecheck the AC's user clues. Some do have a "one shot" mode for energy savings

Comment: don't discount the fact that last few years with smart thermostats how utilities have prevented air conditioning from cooling below a certain temperature, in Texas and California heat waves during times when power grid was stressed, so definitely RTFM and understand the controls of the unit especially if it has wifi,  After observing behavior of Canada gov't last few years I would not be surprised if such a thing could be happening with your AC.  The wall outlet does not have *inadequate* wiring causing a *phenomenon* that is lowering voltage.

Comment: you also did not state the specific make & model of AC, that would go a long way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the ultimate case of RTFM. After reading keshlam's comment I double-checked the manual and, lo and behold, not only was there something similar to what he is describing*, but it was the default setting when you turn on the AC.

I have never seen any AC with this "feature" before moving here. Lesson learned (besides RTFM): regional market differences are very real.

* An "eco mode" that shuts everything off after the desired temperature is met, after which the fans are turned on for a couple of minutes every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I would turn off the breaker and check the outlets/circuits.  There is probably a loose connection somewhere.

If any outlets use the push in connection on the back instead of the screws on the side, change to the screws.  Those push ins are known for problems.

Wire gauge for 15 amp circuits must be 14 gauge/12 for 20 amp circuits.  This has been code for a very long time, probably even before the 50s.

High resistance caused by loose connections will usually match your problems and can cause fires.